# Handle callback function after setState in hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to ask if my approach to using callback functions below is correct. I feel like the callback function I switched from Class to Hooks is not working as expected.

**in Class**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (typeof nextProps.checked != 'undefined' && nextProps.checked != this.state.checked) {
    this.setState({checked: nextProps.checked});
  }
}

onClick = () => {
  var self=this;
  this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked}, function () {
    self.props.onChange(self.state.checked);
  });
};
```

**in Hooks**

```js
const { checked,onChange } = props;
const [state, setState] = useState({
  checked: !!checked
});

useEffect(() => {
  setState({ ...state, checked: checked });
}, [checked]);

useEffect(() => {
  onChange(state.checked)
}, [state.checked]);

const onClick = () => {
  setState({ checked: !state.checked });
}
```

Comment: Isn't ```!!checked``` same as ```checked```?

Comment: @AyushGupta `!!checked` is one common way to convert `checked` to a Boolean. (`Boolean(checked)` is another.) Admittedly, weird that it's done in one case but not within `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

if the upper `props.onChange` handle the `checked` status and pass it down to this component, then you dont need to handle the state internally ?

Comment: I am keeping the state of the child component and when it has changed I will pass that state to the parent component to handle the check all checkbox issue

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and I feel this is working as expected.
You can check here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-firefly-2l4tt?file=/src/App.js

But, seeing your code, I feel you want to pass the status of the checked/unchecked field in the child component to the parent component. In that case, you can directly call onChange props from the child component onClick/onChange event and manage the state independently in the parent component.
Probably, the code of the parent component will help me in better understanding if you could share.

Comment: I tried with onChange={(val) => {
          console.log("logging me...", val);
        }} in parent component but this makes my checkbox check/uncheck continuously

Comment: It seems to be looping infinitely, but if I don't call the onChange function on useEffect it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I request you if you could provide any sandbox with your code. It will be easier to understand.

Comment: It's hard since this is an internal project, I don't know how anymore.